# Roots of $(az + b)^3 = c$, where $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $a,b,c $ are real numbers greater than $0$.

Tags: complex-numbers

**Question:** Find the roots of $(az + b)^3 = c$, where $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $a,b,c $ are real numbers greater than $0$.

**Attempt:** I have solved for roots for questions of the type $z^n = a$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$, by considering the polar form $z_k = a^{1/n}e^{\pi/n(1 + 2k)i}$. However, I'm unsure how to approach this question. Any help?

Comment: Try using a substitution to leverage your existing knowledge, and then solve in two simpler stages.

Comment: A change of variables would help. Find first all the $\hat{z}$ such that $\hat{z}^3 = 1$, applying the formula of unit roots. Then $(c^{1/3} \cdot \hat{z})^3 = c$. Finally write $az + b = c^{1/3} \cdot \hat{z}$ and find one $z$ for each $\hat{z}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: first set $w = az + b$ and solve the system $w^3 = c$ for $w$ using the method you already know. Then can you find $z$?